# Consider cofinite topology on an infinite set X. Is every subset of X either open, or closed, or clopen?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

First, the only clopen sets are $X$ and $\phi$, because if a proper subset $A$ is clopen, then $A$ and $X-A$ are open, so X-A and A are closed and hence finite, giving as $X=A\cup (X-A)$ is finite, which is a contradiction.

Now, as X is infinite, there must be an infinite set $A$ such that its complement $X-A$ is also infinite. So $A$ is neither open nor closed. [A subset is open if its complement is finite, and closed if it is finite. $A$ is neither.]

Is this proof correct? I have intuitively guess the existence of such an $A$ and have not been able to actually prove it.

Comment: You can just give an example. Let $X=\Bbb Z$ and $A=\Bbb Z^+$. Then $A$ is infinite and $A^c$ is infinite. Hence $A$ is neither open nor closed. Proof done.

Comment: Why do you doubt your proof?

Comment: Do you have a definition of "infinite set"?

Comment: @Jochen because I could not given a concrete proof of the existence of such an A

Comment: @ThePortakal That proves the suggested theorem is not true, but it would be a stronger result to say any infinite set has a subset that is neither open nor closed in the cofinite topology.

Comment: Proving that an infinite set has an infinite,co-infinite subset is subtle.  Without the the Axiom of Choice, or at least one of its corollaries, it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative.

Consider the set $\mathbb{Z}$, which is neither open nor closed as subset of real numbers with cofinite topology

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed correct: if $A \subseteq X$ exists with $A$ infinite and $X\setminus A$ infinite, then $A$ is not open (as it's not empty and its complement is not finite) and same holds for its complement, so $A$ is not closed either.

That such a set exists is clear from set theory: e.g. $X$ infinite means that there is a bijection $f$ between $X$ and $X \times \{0,1\}$ and then $A = f^{-1}[X \times \{0\}]$ is such a set.

Comment: Well, perhaps a bit simpler: If $X$ is infinite it contains distinct $x_n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Then $A=\{x_{2n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is infinite as well as $X\setminus A$.

Comment: @Jochen yes, that’s another way to see it.